# What could be the join query for the condition given below?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables Orders table and customers table, both have customerid as common field,

customer table have  firstname, lastname, phone and email address fields.

Now if I have to search/select the orders according to customer firstname and/or lastname and/or phone and/or email and/or orderid, then what should be the mysql format of join query?

> **Additional question related to above**

I have to use a single text box to use for search by order id or first name or last name or phone or email address, how can i Identify the input value to be related to required fields, if u have the idea to make it happen plss guide me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select orders.* 
from orders 
join customers on customers.customerid=orders.customerid
where customers.firstname = 'John' -- or whatever
```

This gives you a list of orders, but you can filter it based on the fields in the Customers table (by changing the `where` clause appropriately).

To address the second question, you can't tell which field the user wants to search on, so you'll have to search on all possible fields. Build up a where-clause like this:

```
where (customers.firstname like '%input%')
   or (customers.lastname like '%input%')
   or (orders.id = 'input')
   or (.. etc)
```

Where `input` is what was typed in the textbox.

Be careful to sanitize the input string though. You should use parameters if you can, or at least replace `'` with `''`.

You don't want the user to be able to enter `'; drop table customers; --` and have that interpreted as SQL code rather than a string.

Comment: Well, it's an answer for you. It's the obvious answer, so I thought you might have some reason not to use it.

Comment: +1 Thanx Blorg pls see the updated question for additional related question of it

Comment: Thanx Blorg thanx for ur time

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM orders JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id=orders.customer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM customers AS c INNER JOIN order AS o ON c.customerid=o.customerid
```

To Order:

```
SELECT * FROM customers AS c INNER JOIN order AS o ON c.customerid=o.customerid ORDER BY c.lastname DESC
```

To Search:

```
SELECT * FROM customers AS c INNER JOIN order AS o ON c.customerid=o.customerid WHERE c.lastname LIKE "%brown%"
```